# Change the border color of view in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UIView` in `UITableView` and I need to change the border color of the `UIView` in a selected row.

How can I do this?

In `UITableView` `cellForRowIndexPath` I declared a `UIView` named as `polygonView`.

In `UITableView` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I wrote code to change the border color.

I also need my row to be unselected when I select a different row.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    polygonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 40, 10, 300, 43)];
     //polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"rectangle_box (2)"];
      polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image1];
    polygonView.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.textLabel.text=[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:polygonView];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
    polygonView .layer.shadowColor = [color CGColor];
    polygonView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
    polygonView  .layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    polygonView   .layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a didDeselectRowAtIndexPath... delegate method you can implement which gets called when you select a different row. From that delegate method you can access the cell (using cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath:deselectedIndexPath) and the polygon to change the border color.